# How to do Finger Tracking which is occluded by an object?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

Basically I want the hand gesture recognition even when I have an object in hand by using a camera (MS Kinect) in front.

My fingers are not visible directly to the camera due to the object. For example if I could project some electromagnetic rays which can pass through the object but not through the hand so that I get some trace of hand in the image. Even using markers on the fingers can be an option. The material of the object can be plastic or something of this sort.

Any help or reference material would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a hand model (using say the kinematics) in order to hypothesize the pose of the articulated movement. For example you can look into:

http://cvrlcode.ics.forth.gr/handtracking/

http://users.ics.forth.gr/~argyros/mypapers/2012_06_cvpr_twohands.pdf

http://robohow.eu/_media/special/bib/isuvr13.pdf

After robustly tracking in presence of the occlusions, you could use a machine learning method such as HMM to recognize the gesture.